# CORS missing allow origins with login_required Django

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, cors, django-cors-headers

here it is my problem as i said in title i have an issue with cors. I created a view with a "login_required" and since i have the error "cors missing allow origin", my get request worked fine before i set the login_required. Im using Django rest Framework i tried everything, i modified settting.py with allow_host, cors_origin_white_list, corsheader in installed app, add header options in  my axios request, etc...

**the view**

```
class essai2(APIView):

    serializer_class = ComSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        Pictos = Pictograms.objects.all()
        data = ComSerializer(Pictos, many=True).data
        if data:
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**the axios request** (im using reactjs)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8002/com/test").then(function (response) {
            console.log("coucou");
            setpictos(response.data);
        })
    }, []);
```

setting.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN = ["http://localhost:3000",]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
     'http://localhost:3000',

]
```

im using the build-in django login system so if there is no user logged in i have a redirect to login page and everything works fine on the server side, datas display when im logged in but i cant get datas on the client side even if there is a user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Is the client side being served on Port 3000?

If not, you need to change the Port number on CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN to whatever Port the client is being served on.

Comment: it was already done thats why it worked before i use login_required but thanks for your help.